# Getting error in playing audio when screen unlock

Tags: android

I am new to this so please let me help that i had an android app that has one button Play. On click of play button it will start playing audio stored in raw folder and button text is changed to pause to it will pause the audio, but when i lock my phone and after unlocking when I press the button I am getting below error.

> 09-05 09:42:57.749: E/AndroidRuntime(11722): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   09-05 09:42:57.749: E/AndroidRuntime(11722): java.lang.IllegalStateException
>   09-05 09:42:57.749: E/AndroidRuntime(11722):    at android.media.MediaPlayer._pause(Native Method)
>   09-05 09:42:57.749: E/AndroidRuntime(11722):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.pause(MediaPlayer.java:1051)
>   09-05 09:42:57.749: E/AndroidRuntime(11722):    at com.example.demo.DemoActivity$1.onClick(DemoActivity.java:57)
>   09-05 09:42:57.749: E/AndroidRuntime(11722):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
>   09-05 09:42:57.749: E/AndroidRuntime(11722):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
>   09-05 09:42:57.749: E/AndroidRuntime(11722):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>   09-05 09:42:57.749: E/AndroidRuntime(11722):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   09-05 09:42:57.749: E/AndroidRuntime(11722):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   09-05 09:42:57.749: E/AndroidRuntime(11722):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
>   09-05 09:42:57.749: E/AndroidRuntime(11722):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   09-05 09:42:57.749: E/AndroidRuntime(11722):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   09-05 09:42:57.749: E/AndroidRuntime(11722):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   09-05 09:42:57.749: E/AndroidRuntime(11722):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>   09-05 09:42:57.749: E/AndroidRuntime(11722):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

My code is as below:

```
public class DemoActivity extends Activity{
MediaPlayer mp;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
mp = MediaPlayer.create(DemoActivity.this,
            R.raw.biii);
final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (btn.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("play")) {
                mp.start();
                btn.setText("Pause");
            } else if (btn.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("pause")) {
                mp.pause();
                btn.setText("Play");
            }
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mp.release();
}
}
```

Comment: media player is released and you wana call pause ... please learn about activty's lifecycle ... to see what happend you should add logs to `onCreate`, `onPause` `onResume` ... after that your logcat would show somthing like *onCreate* , *onResume* ... (now lock the phone) *onPause* ... (after unlock) *onResume* .... (or somthing similar) ... with such information you will be able to think it out

Comment: @Selvin : i tried as you said but if i start the app and lock my phone without playing song and when i unlock and press on play button it gives me error. So can u please give me whole code java code with all method implementation. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `onPause` method you are calling [release()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#release()), which puts the `MediaPlayer` in the `end` state.

You need to override the `onResume` method and call MediaPlayer's [reset()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#reset()) method, which puts `MediaPlayer` in the `idle` state. Then, call [setDataSource()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource(java.lang.String)) with the value of your raw folder to put the `MediaPlayer` in the `initialized` state. Call [prepare()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#prepare()) to prepare your `MediaPlayer` for SYNC tasks or [prepareAsync()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#prepareAsync()) for ASYNC tasks.

You SHOULD (REALLY!) read about MediaPlayer's states. It has it's own [cute little diagram](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram). Be sure to read about Activities as well, because you will only use MediaPlayer effectively if you know how the [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) works.

Comment: Do you have any implementation code with all method that can solve my problem. Thank you